# how to merge two dict on the basis of their process_id

Tags: python, json

dict1 and dict2 needs to be merged to form the final dict which will have the status with each process_id. I have also sent the order of status according to their priority.
the answer is in the merged_dict in the last.

```
master_id_process_list = [
    {
        "process_id": 100,
        "key": "ssn"
    },
    {
        "process_id": 101,
        "key": "ssn"
    }]

process_id_status_list = [
    {
        "process_id": 101,
        "parent_process_id": 100,
        "status": "PASSED"
    }]

process_status = {
    "PASSED": 30,
    "NEEDS_MANUAL_REVIEW": 20,
    "IN_PROGRESS": 10,
    "FAILED": 0
}


merged_dict = [
{
"process_id": 100,
"key": "ssn",
"status": "PASSED"
},
{
"process_id": 101,
"key": "ssn",
"status": "PASSED"
}]
```

Comment: So, what is your question? If you wish to merge two dicts, that'd be {**dict1, **dict2}

Comment: i have given the merged_dict and i want the final output to be like that

Comment: Ahh ok, didnt get that give me a minute

Comment: So you want to add the status attribute, and it counts for the process and the parentprocess too?

Comment: How do you know that process 100 has status PASSED?